# serverless deployment issue

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have created my application using serverless offline. It's working fine. but when I am going deploy on aws it will give me error like below.

> The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 216, is greater than maximum allowed, 200

I will research lots And found following suggestion

1. Use microservices
2. Nested Stack

But I have no idea, how can use it on the existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a CloudFormation limitation. A possible solution would be to split up your large Service into multiple smaller ones.

More automatically you should look into this [plugin](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks)

For more details follow the [link](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/)